# HTML Special Character Decoding not working in CI

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using Code Ignitor for my site. The problem is in the same server the function htmlspecialchars_decode($str); is working but not when I use with CI.

This is my code in controller's function:

```
$meta_d = $this->site_model->lyrics_meta_desc();
$data['meta_desc'] = htmlspecialchars_decode($meta_d);
```

And this in my view:

```
<meta name="description" content="<?php echo character_limiter($meta_desc, 150);?>" />
```

Is there anything I am missing. Or some thing else is to be done for CI. Please suggest.By the way I have loaded text helper for the use of character_limiter.

Comment: did you load the text helper?

Comment: Read the question. He already told that !.

Comment: I would like to tell that I have also used and $meta_desc = strip_tags ( $meta_desc ); before placing it in Meta. It works. But not this function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The given code works as it is intended.

However if you want to get readable text  from the Html entities  such as `&#73;&#39;&#118;&#101;&#32;&#119;&#97;&#108;`  . You need to call `utf8_encode()` after `htmlspecialchars_decode()` .I would advice you to use `html_entity_decode()` as well , since it includes all html entities .

so,

```
$meta_d = $this->site_model->lyrics_meta_desc();
$data['meta_desc'] = utf8_encode(html_entity_decode($meta_d));
```

Comment: @Anwar I'm not able to reproduce what you are saying,  can you give the string you are passing.

Comment: Actually the page is the page for lyrics. and my lyrics are in HTML special characters. For eg. &#73;&#39;&#118;&#101;&#32;&#119;&#97;&#108;&#107;&#101;&#100;&#32;&#97;&#108;&#111;&#110;&#101; .... and so on . And I need to put some lines of lyrics in my meta tag. For this I need to decode those special chars. Its running in my local server or live server without using Code Ignitor. But when I try it with code Ignitor. It doesnt work.

Comment: @Anwar Did you just give me random special chars or you gave sample of the actual meta_desc?.

Comment: Thats the actual data. You may refer to http://www.letmesingthis.com/here-i-stand-2008/forever-young-65807/lyrics

Comment: @Anwar  It's decoding perfectly in my codeigniter setup.  with html decode at either ends.

Comment: @Anwar I'm getting the exact same html  as the site when i decode the string and then limit it .  not the readable text, but as the html entities ( when seen in source , as you can see meta only in the source ).

Comment: That worked.. but still some characters are not decoded. It gave out put like I&#39;ve walked alone and.. felt as If no one cared &#8230;

Comment: @Anwar  are you looking at the page source?. It is supposed to show symbols as entities!!. Those things are exclamation marks and other symbols.

Comment: @Anwar  i believe that the above ( edited ) solution clears your problem. Mark it as solution if you are satisfied. :-).

Comment: Oh... That didn't worked. But whether I use utf8_encode or not, Even when I increase character_limiter the meta stops at I&#39;ve walked alone and.. felt as If no one cared &#8230;

Comment: utf8_encode() will make sure that you will get readable text out of it. html_entity_decode() does decode everything it can.

Comment: @Anwar  that's the output you are supposed to see.  special symbols cannot be shown as special symbols when you see the markup. if you print it in a <p>  , it will be readable!.

Comment: I noticed thru various lyrics that the meta description listing stops whenever &#8230; is found

Comment: @Anwar  Dude!!! &#8230;  is the ...  ( three dots ) symbol that character limiter puts at its end. it doesnt stop decoding. :-\.  Now you are not talking sane.

Comment: [Refer](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/text_helper.html).  Read . Study.  Observe. Now this solution helps as much as it can. I believe.

Comment: Why would I like to be insane? Please check the meta desc of http://www.letmesingthis.com/here-i-stand-2008/prayer-for-you/lyrics

Comment: @Anwar  so what you are saying is that   &#8230;   comes at the end of all  character_limiter()  strings... that's because it's limiting!!.. it's adding &#8230;  to make it look neat!. Stop using character_limiter then!

Comment: It's not stopping decoding or it's not stopping anywhere. YOU are limiting it till there. character_limiter has a maximum limit of  20 or 30 characters.